# Subtract Image' mean from itself for a batch of images in Tensorflow

Tags: image, tensorflow, normalization

I would like to subtract the mean of the image from itself given a batch of images.

Obviously, the `tf.image.per_image_standardization` is not what I want since I don't want to divide by the standard deviation.

And, `frames_normalized = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.reduce_mean(frame, axis=[2]), frames_contrast_adjust)` is not what I want since that will reduce the dimensions of the original image. That is, if the dimension of a single image is [112, 112, 3] the result of the `tf.reduce_mean` image will has a shape of [112, 112]. Therefore, the size of `frame_normalized` will become: [?, ?, 112, 3] when `frames_contrast_adjust` is a batch of images of size: [?, 112, 112, 3].

Please note that I do want to use queues in the mean.

Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the op which behaves almost like `per_image_standadization` but without variance, you can just look how [tf.image.per_image_standadization](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.2/tensorflow/python/ops/image_ops_impl.py#L791) is implemented and remove all the stuff related to variance (I commented it away):

```
image = ops.convert_to_tensor(image, name='image')
image = control_flow_ops.with_dependencies(_Check3DImage(image, require_static=False), image)
num_pixels = math_ops.reduce_prod(array_ops.shape(image))

image = math_ops.cast(image, dtype=dtypes.float32)
image_mean = math_ops.reduce_mean(image)

#variance = (math_ops.reduce_mean(math_ops.square(image)) -math_ops.square(image_mean))
#variance = gen_nn_ops.relu(variance)
#stddev = math_ops.sqrt(variance)

# Apply a minimum normalization that protects us against uniform images.
#min_stddev = math_ops.rsqrt(math_ops.cast(num_pixels, dtypes.float32))
#pixel_value_scale = math_ops.maximum(stddev, min_stddev)
pixel_value_offset = image_mean

image = math_ops.subtract(image, pixel_value_offset)
#image = math_ops.div(image, pixel_value_scale)
return image
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by setting the `keep_dims` parameter in `tf.reduce_mean` to true. Now:
`tf.map_fn(lambda frame: tf.reduce_mean(frame, axis=[2], keep_dims=True), frames_contrast_adjust)`

And to subtract the mean of image from the image itself, I did the following:

`frames_normalized = tf.map_fn(lambda frame: frame - tf.reduce_mean(frame, axis=[2], keep_dims=True), input_frames)`